# Begin-EndReceive don't see arrived data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, mono, wireshark

My TCP client stucks when receiving data.

1. Connection established
2. Client sends 21 bytes. (see #5)
3. Next BeginReceive call on the client never invokes the callback. When I force it to call EndReceive it hangs forever. IsCompleted = false.

Some data arrives after #5 but the problem is it never gets to my application. TcpClient.Available returns 135.

The client can send data but it doesn't receive anything from the server.

[image: wireshark window]

The client runs in Unity3D with Mono 2.6. I can reproduce it only with the first launch inside Unity Editor. The second time it starts fine but stucks randomly (outside editor too).

So, why this happens?

[Wireshark log](http://aqla.net/temp/wrlog.pcapng) (set filter tcp.port == 21050).

**UPDATE: Another example**

NoDelay = true, Blocking = false,  LingerState.Enabled = false, Linger = 0

Send operation uses `Socket.Send`, receive operation uses `Socket.Begin-End-Receive`.

Server log:

```
500: Server started
7832: 1: Next receive scheduling for time 25
7863: 1: BeginReceive, available: 0
7925: 1: About to process received data: 21
7925: 1: Processing received data 21 // hello
7941: 1: Send 4  // handshake
7972: 1: Send 8  // init data
8050: 1: Send 41 // init data
8050: 1: Processing received data finished
8050: 1: Next receive scheduling for time 0
8050: 1: BeginReceive, available: 0
8237: 1: Send 86 // init data
8331: 1: About to process received data: 45
8331: 1: Processing received data 45 // set position (x,y,z)
8346: 1: Processing received data finished
8346: 1: Next receive scheduling for time 0
8346: 1: BeginReceive, available: 0
9906: 1: About to process received data: 2
9906: 1: Processing received data 2 // ping
9906: 1: Send 4 // ping response, never reaches client
9906: 1: Processing received data finished
9906: 1: Next receive scheduling for time 0
9906: 1: BeginReceive, available: 0
```

Client log:

```
1: BeginReceive, available: 0
1: Send 21 // hello
1: EndReceive, available 0
1: About to process received data: 4
1: Processing received data 4 // handshake
1: Processing received data finished
1: Next receive scheduling for time 0
1: BeginReceive, available: 135
1: EndReceive, available 0
1: About to process received data: 135 // 8 + 41 + 86
1: Processing received data 135 // init data
1: Processing received data finished
1: Next receive scheduling for time 0
1: Send 45 // set position (x,y,z)
1: BeginReceive, available: 0
1: Send 2  // ping

Waiting ping result too long
No receive for long time, force finish, completed: False

1: EndReceive, available 0 // blocks forever
```

Wireshark shows that 4-length packet arrived. If server keeps sending packets then they are being queued on the client socket (Available > 0).

Comment: No one can tell you what's wrong with your code if you don't post the code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PeterDuniho my question is about behavior, not code. WS indicates that data arrived. My code called BeginReceive, TcpClient.Available > 0 but callback is not firing. EndReceive blocks like there is no data. What do you want to know also?

Comment: If you had written your code correctly, and data was sent to your program via the TCP connection used in your code, a receive completion would have been signaled. Either your client is connected to some remote end point other than the one you think, or there's something wrong with your code. Thus, if you're sure the client is connected to your program's end point, then there's something wrong with your code. No one can tell you what that is if you don't post a proper code example.

Comment: "a receive completion would have been signaled" - I think so too. But it hasn't. Because of this fact I'm asking here. It should but it doesn't. Something is broken. I can't post here the whole network framework project. And the problem is hard to reproduce. I'll try to make an example but I can't just extract some code and test it (because it's a complicated framework). I have to write a simplified version from scratch and I'm not sure that it will reproduce the problem.

Comment: "Something is broken." Yes. And it's in your code. No, you shouldn't post the whole network framework project's code. That would be inappropriate. But you shouldn't be creating a simplified version from scratch; start with the broken code and start removing things not relevant to the example. Eventually one of two things will happen: you will have a nice, small example you can post here and which reproduces the problem, or you'll get to a point where the problem no longer happens. If the latter occurs, then whatever the last thing you removed is, that's where your bug is.

Comment: Available > 0 but receive is not ending. It should never happen and it doesn't depend on my code, it's mono bug.

Comment: Attached logs for all socket method calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be mono bug related to the fact that mono does not support using non-blocking sockets with async API together like MS .NET does. I needed to use non-blocking mode for send operations because of performance reasons. I replaced non-blocking Send with SendAsync and BeginReceive with ReceiveAsync and now it's fixed. And with some effort I made SendAsync work as fast as non-blocking Send does.

Comment: Is the mono bug you are referring to documented somewhere?

Comment: @decden, it was pretty long time ago, as I remember I found it mentioned somewhere but not sure